# Recursive declaration of function pointer in C

Tags: c, c89

I'd like to declare a function that returns a pointer to a function of the same type.

I would like to use it to implement state machines like the one below:

```
typedef event_handler_t (*event_handler_t)(event_t*); // compilation error

event_handler_t state2(event_t* e);
event_handler_t state1(event_t* e) {
    switch(e->type) {
    //...
    case SOME_EVENT:
        return state2;
    //...
    }

}
event_handler_t state2(event_t* e) {
    switch(e->type) {
    //...
    case OTHER_EVENT:
        return state1;
    //...
    }   
}

//...
event_handler_t event_handler;
//...
event_handler(&e);
//...
```

I manage to work around the compliation error using structures as follows:

```
typedef struct event_handler {
    struct event_handler (*func)(event_t *);
} event_handler_t;
```

But this makes return statment more complicated:

```
event_handler_t state2(event_t* e) {
{
    event_handler_t next_handler = {NULL};
    switch(e->type) {
    //...
    case OTHER_EVENT:
        next_handler.func = state1;
        break;
    //...
    } 
    return next_handler;
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way to create such function pointers in c.

Comment: See also: [SO 816356](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816356/how-can-i-typedef-a-function-pointer-that-takes-a-function-of-its-own-type-as-an)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in C: a function can't return a pointer to itself, since the type declaration expands recursively and never ends. See this page for an explanation: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm

The workaround described on the above page means returning `void (*) ()` instead of the correctly-typed function pointer; your workaround is arguably a little neater.

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in Herb Sutter's book **More Exceptional C++**, Item 32, where the answer seems to be (for C) "not without use of casts". For C++ it is possible with the usual introduction of a class to provide some extra indirection.