# How can I typedef a function pointer that takes a function of its own type as an argument?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

Example: A function that takes a function (that takes a function (that ...) and an int) and an int.

```
typedef void(*Func)(void (*)(void (*)(...), int), int);
```

It explodes recursively where `(...)`. Is there a fundamental reason this can't be done or is there another syntax? It seems to me it should be possible without a cast. I'm really trying to pass a dispatch-table but I could figure that out if I could just pass this one type.

Comment: Does it explode recursively, or does it interpret the "..." as a vararg without you actually specifying a previous arg where the vararg point must start from?

Comment: I know I saw a SO question almost exactly like this, but I can't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/793449/10396

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap the function pointer in a struct:

```
struct fnptr_struct;
typedef void (*fnptr)(struct fnptr_struct *);
struct fnptr_struct {
  fnptr fp;
};
```

I'm not sure if this is an improvement on casting. I suspect that it's impossible without the struct because C requires types to be defined before they are used and there's no opaque syntax for typedef.

Comment: Nice that there is a workaround, sad it doesn't "just work".  Ah, legacy.  :-/

Answer (score 6):

It's impossible to do directly.  Your only options are to make the function pointer argument accept unspecified arguments, or to accept a pointer to a structure containing the function pointer, as [Dave suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816356/how-can-i-typdef-a-function-pointer-that-takes-a-function-of-its-own-type-as-an-a/816386#816386).

```
// Define fnptr as a pointer to a function returning void, and which takes one
// argument of type 'pointer to a function returning void and taking
// an unspecified number of parameters of unspecified types'
typedef void (*fnptr)(void (*)());
```