# Is it possible to make recursive type definition in C

Tags: c, syntax, types

I want to define a function type, that returns a pointer to same type of function as itself. I have tried this:

```
typedef state* (*state)(lex*);
```

But I get a `syntax error` as you would guess.

Comment: You could make it return void *

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible.

Comment: So the function returns a pointer to a function which returns a pointer to a function which returns.... What is the return type? The return type is the return type.

Comment: sounds like it is going to be a hard to read program

Comment: @mikejones - No, function pointers and data pointers cannot be used interchangeably. To use `void *` to store a function pointer will result in undefined behaviour when the function is called via the pointer.

Comment: @detly  you can do it in POSIX C.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c

Comment: Voting to reopen, so that it can be properly deduplicated: this question is a duplicate of [SO 816356](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816356/how-can-i-typedef-a-function-pointer-that-takes-a-function-of-its-own-type-as-an) (which asks for a solution to this problem), not of [SO 793449](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793449/recursive-declaration-of-function-pointer-in-c) (which actually answers *this* question, but then asks if a better solution/workaround exists).