# Member functions returning pointers to member functions

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'd like to have a class with member functions that return pointers to member functions.

That is, something like:

```
class Foo {
// typedef ????(Foo::* func)????
public:
   Func s1();
   Func s2();
   Func s3();
}

Func Foo::s1() {
  // do stuff
  return &Foo::s2;
}

Func Foo::s2() {
  // do stuff
  return &Foo::s3;
}

Func Foo::s3() {
  // do stuff
  return 0;
}
```

Basically, what I try to do is to implement a state machine, where each state nows the next state and returns it by means of a function pointer.

Note: I'm not interested in other ways of implementing a state machine. I really like to know if it can be implemented in a way that looks like the above.

Context: I got inspired by this talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE and wondered if a similar pattern can be used in C++.

Comment: [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) are your friends.

Comment: You'd need something like `using Func = Func(Foo::*)();` - which is not allowed.

Comment: You can do this with function objects, but not functions/member functions.

Comment: What you want is a type dependent on itself (A recursive type?), which is obviously not allowed.

Comment: GotW on this: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm

Comment: @SamCristall copy the last section here and we have a winner.

Comment: This isn't even possible for non-member functions (where you can find quite some duplicates). The type had to be *pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning...*.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/793449/420683 and with the same `struct` workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19349061/420683

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blatently ripping off the solution at [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm) and adapting it to member functions:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    struct FuncPtrRet;
    typedef FuncPtrRet(Foo::*FuncPtr)();
    struct FuncPtrRet {
        FuncPtrRet(FuncPtr pp) : p(pp) { }
        operator FuncPtr() { return p; }
        FuncPtr p;
    };
    FuncPtrRet s1() { return &Foo::s2; }
    FuncPtrRet s2() { return &Foo::s3; }
    FuncPtrRet s3() { return &Foo::s3; }
};

int main() {
    Foo test;
    Foo::FuncPtr state = test.s1();
    state = (test.*state)();
    state = (test.*state)();
    state = (test.*state)();
    state = (test.*state)();
    state = (test.*state)();
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work on Clang 3.3.  I don't think returning 0 is a good choice for an idle state (s3 here), but I might be wrong there.  Having an idle state that returns itself seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much it! Pretty cool although it shows a bit that functional programming in C++ is not really straightforward. With respect to returning 0, this allows you to do something like:

    for (FuncPtrRet state = test.s1(); state != 0; ) {
       state = (test.*state)();
    }

Comment: Functional programming in C++ looks a lot better without member function pointers.  Member function pointer syntax is atrocious.