# C++: How to return a pointer to a non-static member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I want to do something like this:

```
typedef int(A::*f_ptr)(int);
class A
{
    int f1(int a){ /*do something*/ }
    int f2(int a){ /*do something else*/ }
    f_ptr pick_f(int i)
    {
         if(i)
              return this->f1;
         return this->f2;
    }
}
```

The reason is that I want instances of class A to hold certain useful variables and later on to just pick the member functions that I need depending on user input. But this does not work because I get the "a pointer to a bound function can only be used to call the function". How can I write a function that returns a pointer to a non-static member function?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600044/member-functions-returning-pointers-to-member-functions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return the address of the member functions, like this:

```
f_ptr pick_f(int i)
{  
  if(i)
    return &A::f1;
  return &A::f2;
}
```

Or the equivalent terser version:

```
f_ptr pick_f(int i)
{
  return i ? &A::f1 : &A::f2;
}
```

Comment: To expand, what you've done here is "unbound" them. That is, there is no long a `this` pointer "bound". Hence the error message.