# iterate + forever = iterateM? Repeating an action with feedback

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to repeat an IO action forever, but feeding the result of one execution into the next. Something like this:

```
-- poorly named
iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m b
iterateM f a = f a >>= iterateM f
```

Hoogle didn't seem to help me, but I see plenty of functions which look enticingly close to what I want, but none seem to come together to be exactly it.

Comment: I created an `iterateM_` function as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699912/clean-and-type-safe-state-machine-implementation-in-a-statically-typed-language/7700185#7700185).

Comment: @pat: glad to see I wasn't the only one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, I don't know of a place this particular kind of loop is implemented. Your implementation looks fine; why not submit it as a patch to the [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I would expect an `iterateM` combinator to have this type signature:

```
iterateM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]
```

Of course this is not a very useful combinator, because you couldn't extract the result in most monads.  A more sensible name to go with the base naming standard for your combinator would be `iterateM_`:

```
iterateM_ :: (Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> m b
iterateM_ f = fix $ \again x -> f x >>= again
```

This combinator can be useful:

```
countFrom :: (Enum a) => a -> IO b
countFrom = iterateM_ (\x -> succ x <$ print x)
```

However, for the sake of simplicity I would just go with `fix` or explicit recursion.  The explicitly recursive code isn't much longer or much less readable:

```
countFrom :: (Enum a) => a -> IO b
countFrom = fix (\again x -> print x >> again (succ x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up re: the name—you're right. Thanks also for the examples!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason you don't see this in the standard libraries is because it will never terminate.  The iterate function can leverage lazy lists to allow you to specify termination using the `take` function on the result list.  Here, your result is monadic, so this isn't possible.

Obviously the spirit of your idea can be done.  It just has to look a little different:

```
iterateM :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
iterateM 0 _ a = return a
iterateM n f a = f a >>= iterateM (n-1) f
```

Comment: Indeed, this is true, but the use case is different too! (i.e. I'm not expecting it to terminate, much as the user of `forever` isn't.)

Comment: There are of course exceptions and `System.Exit`, but those shouldn't normally be (ab)used for breaking a loop on purpose.

Comment: Len: Ahhh, I see.  I guess just use your definition.  I don't know of anything in standard libraries doing that.

Comment: Couldn't something like `(a -> MaybeT m a) -> a -> m a` work?

Comment: @leftaroundabout hey, I wrote almost that exact thing recently! See `loopM` in https://github.com/DanBurton/bf-interp/blob/master/Program.hs -- instead of `return ()` you could `return a` and get the precise signature you were looking for.

Comment: @DanBurton: thanks for the link! It should surprise no-one that this came about in implementing a (naïve) stepping function for a VM. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be written in terms of `forever` using `StateT`.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Monad (forever)

iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m b
iterateM f = evalStateT $ forever $ get >>= lift . f >>= put
```

Comment: Thanks! This clarifies some things in my mind about `lift`, too.