# Grokking Random Number Generation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I have a function `probabilities :: String -> [(String, Double)]` which returns a probability distribution based on an input `String`. Now I want to generate a new random `String` based on that probability distribution with a function something like `generate :: String -> String`. I recently find [`fromList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html#v%3afromList) in `Control.Random.Monad`, but I'm struggling with using it for my specific situation. Can anyone help point me in the right direction here? If you need more information, please ask.

**More Information:**

I need to be able to call `generate` repeatedly for use in another algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need monads. Let's change the type of `generate` to:

```
generate :: (MonadRandom m) => String -> m String
```

Then you can define `generate` as you might expect:

```
generate = fromList . probabilities
```

You can repeatedly call `generate` from another function `foo` in two ways:

In both cases, we'll need [`iterateM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801036/iterate-forever-iteratem-repeating-an-action-with-feedback) (also in [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html))

```
iterateM :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
iterateM 0 _ a = return a
iterateM n f a = f a >>= iterateM (n-1) f
```

1. Foo can be monadic:

   ```
   foo :: (MonadRandom m) => String -> m String
   foo = iterateM 10 generate
   ```
2. Or you can create a state and make `foo` pure:

   ```
    foo :: Int -> String -> String
    foo seed str = evalRand (iterateM 10 generate str) (mkStdGen seed)
   ```

Comment: Thanks, `fromList . probabilities` is exactly what I am looking for as far as the root of my OP here.