# `mfix` not working as expected

Tags: haskell, monads

I expected the following code to first prompt `start:`, then wait for a user response, before echoing the previous user response back, and awaiting a new one:

```
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
import Control.Monad.Fix (mfix)

f :: [String] -> IO [String]
f = mapM $ \x -> putStr x >> putStr ": " >> hFlush stdout >> getLine

g x = f ("start":x)

main = mfix g
```

But it gives the error `thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation` after the first line is entered.

Why is this and how can I fix it (excuse the pun)?

Comment: this might shed some light on it: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/System-IO.html#fixIO (I think it's because your `f` and `g` are both strict and that's no good idea here - but I do not claim to be able to really think about what's happening here ;)) - why do you want the `mfix` anyway?

Comment: I basically have two functions, `f :: [a] -> [b]` and `g :: [b] -> IO [a]` and I need to join the outputs of each other to their inputs (so they basically talk to one another). Obviously I can make `h = g . f` which makes `h :: [a] -> IO [a]` but I can't figure out how to tie the knot. I thought `mfix` would work but it doesn't seem too.

Comment: so you do not have the *first* input and really want to find a fix-point? Because if you have any starting point than you could just do a simple recursion (or most likely I just don't see it) - can you have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/606771cd7b6a9123bea3 - based on what you wrote first `dialog` there should do what you want - if you are ok with it I will make it an answer, but I'm not sure because of the strang mfix/mapM there

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `[a]` as `Event a` or `Behavior a` in an FRP framework. Why not use one of the existing frameworks that supports this sort of operation?

Comment: @CarstenKönig: I just want to tie together `f` and `g` like I've said. I don't care how it's done. However, I want this to work with all `f` and `g` of the same type.

As in, write a function `h f g :: ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> IO [a]) -> IO ()` that does what I'm looking for, using mfix or otherwise.

Note I can tie two functions together trivially if they both don't involve monads, so I'm not sure why the monads (in this case IO)) should stop it.

Comment: Can you rewrite `f` and `g` in terms of `a -> a`/`a -> IO a` rather than with the lists?

Comment: @ChristianConkle: I guess I could, but in your answer could you explain why you can tie a function `[a] -> [a]` to itself but not a function `[a] -> m [a]` to itself? If Haskell is lazy, surely you can get a partial result out of the monad before it completes yes (@ØrjanJohansen has talked about the strictness of `mapM` below, perhaps it can be explained why a lazy version can not be created).

Answer (score 7):

The reason why this can't work is that in `mfix f` runs any effect in `f` exactly once. This follows from the tightening rule

```
mfix (\x -> a >>= \y -> f x y)  =  a >>= \y -> mfix (\x -> f x y)
```

in particular

```
mfix (\x -> a >> f x)  =  a >> mfix f
```

for any correct instance of `MonadFix`. So the fixed point is only computed for the pure (lazily computed) value inside the monadic action, *not* for the effects. In your case using `mfix` asks for printing/reading characters just once in such a way that the input is equal to the output, which is impossible. This isn't a proper use case for `mfix`. You'd use `mfix` with `IO` for example to construct a cyclic data structure in `IO` like in [these examples](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadFix#Imperative_cyclic_linked_lists).

In your case you should use [`iterateM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:iterateM_) or something similar rather than `mfix`. see also [iterate + forever = iterateM? Repeating an action with feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10801036/1333025).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `mfix` in the `IO` monad doesn't really work to produce lists piecemeal like that. This is because most actions in the `IO` monad are very strict: they don't produce *any* part of their result until the whole action has been performed. In particular, `mapM` in `IO` will not return any part of its result list until it has gone through all of its input list, which leaves `mfix` with no hope of tying the knot in the right way here.

In general, `mfix` in `IO` really only works if the tied-back value isn't looked at strictly until after the whole `mfix` action is completed. This still *has* some possible uses, like initializing a data structure with cycles of mutable cells using only `newIORef`.