# Is there a way to declare an objective-C block typedef whose arguments contain that typedef?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-blocks, typedef

Here's an interesting one for the objective-C gurus out there...

Is there a way to declare an objective-C block typedef that contains an argument of that typedef?

```
typedef BOOL (^SSCellAction) ( UITableViewController* inTVC, SSCellAction inChainedAction );
```

The idea is that I wanted to used chained menu action system that allows a chain of work/response to occur (usually 1-3 items).  When the last action invokes, it passes nil for `inChainedAction`.  Since this seems relatively trivial to imagine, I'll be dammed if I can't figure out how to declare it without llvm saying no.  :)

Comment: I think you should just have a second typedef for the continuation that has the same arguments.

Comment: How would you do that @jeffamaphone ?

Comment: Ah, yeah.  Nevermind.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is possible. It's essentially the same issue in C as trying to `typedef` a function that has same function as itself for a parameter. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793449/recursive-declaration-of-function-pointer-in-c and related questions.

Comment: Like adding an array into itself I think this can cause serious problems in memory management.

Comment: Well, a counter analogy is that a struct can contain a ptr of the same type because the nature of a struct ptr is still just a ptr.  Likewise, a specific block typedef is still a block typedef. For example, a blind ref could be passed in and then internally/privately reform into its original type, complete with all its properties.   @maddy

Comment: @RASS This issue is nothing like adding an array to itself (which can be done without any issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rmaddy's comment is correct. Just as in C, a `typedef` cannot use itself. Basically, a `typedef` does not make a real type, but just makes an alias that the compiler expands out at compile-time. It is always possible to manually expand all `typedef`s in your program yourself (which is sometimes an instructive exercise), so that your program is written without `typedef`s. However, a recursive `typedef` cannot be expanded.

Some possible workarounds:

- Use `id` as the parameter type, and cast back into the right type inside the block. This loses type safety.
- Or, use a struct type of one member, the block. A struct is a real type, so it can be used within its definition. The downside of this is that you explicitly "wrap" the block into the struct type to pass it, and explicitly "unwrap" the struct into the block by accessing the field when you need to call it. This way is type-safe.

Comment: sounds like two great ways the objC processor could insert to expand acceptance in order to support the original goal.  it'd be great to hear from an objC dev in detail. i'm curious if it can or can't be added in the future if we agree that @newacct's deterministic workarounds are correct.

Comment: @DrewO'Meara: I think it's possible to add an extension to C to support recursive function or block typedefs. It wouldn't have to do with Objective-C specifically. But I don't think anyone plans on doing that.