# Typedef for a function that returns the pointer to the same type

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I want to typedef a function for a state machine, that returns pointer to the same type of function as itself. I have tried;

```
typedef StateFunc *(*StateFunc)(struct lexer *);
```

But unfortunately,

> lexer.c:60:9: error: unknown type name 'StateFunc'  typedef StateFunc
>   *(*StateFunc)(struct lexer *);

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't know how can I do that?

Comment: It's actually not possible, since it's a recursive declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in C. A workaround involving structs can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793449/recursive-declaration-of-function-pointer-in-c (the question itself), and a link to more info in the accepted answer.